# How to pull only particular files from a git repository?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have 2 repositories A and B.

I wanted to pull only some of the files from repository A to repository B.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind pulling the entire repository A (i.e. you aren’t worried about saving on download time for some reason), you should be able to pull to another branch:

```
git pull --no-commit <URI for repository A> master:temp-branch
```

Then you can either merge `temp-branch` automatically or cherry-pick commits from it (if you really wanted to merge some patches instead of files, or if the files were added in one or more convenient commits).

Alternatively, if you don’t want repository A’s history, but having all its files somewhere is okay:

```
git clone --depth 1 <URI for repository A> somewhere
```

Answer (score 0):

Git is not a file-oriented SCM. History is based on trees, so you can't ask Git to check out only a single file from a remote repository.

However, if you're using a repository browser interface (e.g. as provided by Github) or gitweb, you can certainly download individual raw files from the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you want to deal with files not commits, is to do it outside of git, i.e. with a setup of

```
files/project_1 # Includes a .git directory at this level.
files/project_2 # Same here.
```

you can do

```
cp files/project_2/your_spec*.* files/project_1/
```

then

```
cd files/project_1
git add .
git commit -m"msg"
```